# Custom Header for specific URL in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, header

How can I insert some javascript into my header for a specific URL?

It isn't a page or post, but www.myblog.com/tag/funny/

Thank you.  Here is the script I am trying to us.

```
<?php if (is_tag('funny') ) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://media.dfd.com/Test/trafficregenerator.js">

</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [is_tag( 'funny' )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tag). It will return true if the tag archive page is shown. You can use the parameter to specify a tag, or leave it blank for any tag archive page.

So,

```
if( is_tag( 'funny' ) ) :
  wp_enqueue_script( 'trafficregenerator', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/trafficregenerator.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
endif;
```

Make sure you are adding this to the template file, not the themes functions.php.

You need to review the path to the script and may not need the jquery dependency depending on what the script uses (in which case change the parameter to array() ). The '1.0' is just a version number and the final 'true' says, put it before the closing body tag.

Comment: This won't work...   <?php
if( is_tag( 'cap' ) ) :
  wp_enqueue_script('trafficscript.js');
 endif; ?>

Comment: Read about how to use [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) first...

Comment: @Mike, you are not using wp_enqueue_script correctly - As RRikesh says learn how to use them and it will work. See the WordPress codex for [wp_register_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for more information.

Comment: I think I am doing it right now, but the problem is it shows on every page that has a 'funny' tag.  Not only the url www.myblog.com/tag/funny/

Comment: Ok, can you edit your question to include the code you're using now and if possible a link.

Comment: <?php if (is_tag('funny') ) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://media.dfd.com/Test/trafficregenerator.js">

</script>
<?php } ?>

Comment: I am sorry so I am bad with this sort of stuff.  I kept testing different ways and it never worked.  Really frustrating.  No one I work with can figure it out either.